# Unable to load DLL jvm.dll The specified module could not be found Azure Data Factory V2 error

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

We are trying to copy data from on-premise SQL Server to Azure Blob storage. But we are facing below error :

> Activity Copy_741 failed: Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorJreNotFound,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Java Runtime Environment could not be found.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=System.DllNotFoundException,Message=Unable to load DLL 'jvm.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E),Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.HiveOrcBridge,'

On some other post, we found we need to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package on Integration Runtime node but the latest version is already installed.

We are using Azure data factory v2. Also, we are able to transfer data from Azure SQL Server to Blob without any problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Converting to ORC files requires the Java Runtime Environment to be installed on your self-hosted integration runtime. If you have already double-checked that you have the JRE and the C++ 2010 Redistributable installed, here are some other things to check:

- Confirm that your copy activity is using the correct integration runtime in ADF.
- Double-check that the IR and JRE match bit-wise (e.g., both 64-bit)
- Check that JAVA_HOME is set correctly in the environment variables
- Check the registry key – HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment should have a Current Version entry that shows the current JRE version

Comment: I am using an auto-resolve Azure-hosted runtime but still getting this error

I would think they would have the environment necessary to handle this?

Comment: Can the OP indicate which of these 4 things was the actual issue?

Comment: The `JAVA_HOME` was missing for me.

Answer (score 2):

It might be related to [Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/download_options.xml) not being installed on the relevant machine.

Hope it helps!